# Bukkit - How to read from a YML file and use in an if statements

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to read data from my config.yml. It's saving data like (playerName: value). I want to check, if player's name value is equals to 0, then ban him. But still don't know how to read those values. I was searching around spigot forum but nothing worked.

```
@EventHandler
    public void OnDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getEntity().getPlayer();
        String playerName = player.getName();

        int lives;

        if (!livesMap.containsKey(player)) {
            // Set the default amount of lives to 2. (3 minus 1, since the player already died once)
            lives = 2;

            plugin.getConfig().set(playerName, lives);
            plugin.saveConfig();
        } else {
            // Subtract one from the player's lives
            lives = livesMap.get(player) - 1;

            // Saving playerName and lives
            plugin.getConfig().set(playerName, lives);
            plugin.saveConfig();
        }

        livesMap.put(player, lives);
```

My data is saving like this, but i want to know what method should i use to read values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky for you, bukkit already has classes you can use for this!

```
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;

FileConfiguration config = getConfig();
```

This call will inherently load your config.yml file.

You can then access values by doing something like this:

```
config.getString("yml.object.here");
```

Let me know if you have any other questions!

TIP: If you store your player names in a list you can get a list of them!

Comment: I can't get player's name by "yml.object". I saved data like (plugin.getConfig().set(playerName, lives)) then im trying to read this like getConfig().getString(playerName), put it into variable, and this variable is int, not player's name.

Comment: I was just giving you an example. If you are storing values under player's names, then you should use getConfig().getInt("playername") as answered by SteffenJacobs. The more subtle point I was trying to make is that you might want to reconsider how you are saving this information. It seems to me that if you store a players life with his name as the key, you will have to arbitrarily iterate your list of players to check what their lives are... You might want to consider making a playerLives obj that lives in mem so you don't have to read and write every death.

Comment: I got it, i am just stupid, trying to get key, not the value of that key. It works perfectly for me. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Hey, Kasjan, if you are satisfied, would you please accept this as the answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`plugin.getConfig().getInt(playerName)`.